# Local Host web not showing to other diveces connected to same network

Tags: networking, localhost, ip, port, router

So when i go live with live-server or with npm start in react i have seen youtube videos that you can access your web from other devices connected to the same network.But my problem is that even if i have created new **Inbound Rules** on windows defender firewall  to allow the connection,even if i disabled the windows defender firewall when i try **http://*myIpAdress*:*port*/** the webpage don't open.

I think the problem is with my router i expect to view my website on other devices

Comment: If you are on the same network, then the router never sees the traffic. Routers route packets _between_ networks, not from a network back to the same network.

Comment: @RonMaupin thank you for replaying but i dont understand it.Do you know is any fix for this?